# PHP and Apache : shell_exec(wkhtmltopdf with xvfb) command doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, wkhtmltopdf, shell-exec, xvfb

I try to run the wkhtmltopdf (0.11.0 rc1) with php (5.4.2) on apache (2.4.2).
When I try to launch `wkhtmltopdf-i386 --use-xserver http://www.google.com google.pdf 2>&1`, I can find my pdf. Here my php code

```
<?php
    $cmd= '/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf-i386 http://www.google.com google.pdf 2>&1';
    $ret = shell_exec($cmd);
    echo $ret;
?>
```

It works with apache and as command line `php test.php`.
Because my target page contains many images and some "heavy" js charts. I have got a Segmentation Fault with the wkhtmltopdf command when I try to turn it into pdf.
The only way to make it work is to use xvfb as X11 emulator. The code looks like this :

```
<?php
    $cmd= '/usr/bin/xvfb-run  /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf-i386 --use-xserver http://www.google.com google.pdf 2>&1';
    $ret = shell_exec($cmd);
    echo $ret;
?>
```

This script works with the command line `php test.php` but it doesn't work with apache. If I take a look into the apache's process with `htop`, I can see that there are two process (with `php test.php`) :

- xvfb
- wkhtmltopdf

When I launch with apache I have only xvfb process. It finish by a timeout from apache because it's waiting the wkhtmltopdf process.

I can make it works with apache (2.2.21) and php (5.3.10).

Is there something that I'm missing ? Maybe something in the apache's config-files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I was using the exec function, but the same applies to shell_exec. The function execution was disabled in php.ini.

SOLUTION: Remove the shell_exec string from the disable_functions at php.ini file.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your second version is not callable from Apache (must not be using the same shell, since `shell_exec` uses a shell?), but as a work-around could you (from Apache PHP) `shell_exec("php test.php");` and get your intended result?

Perhaps also try one of the other process execution functions such as [pcntl_exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-exec.php).

Comment: I've tried to do so but I still only have xvfb process launched.

Answer (score 0):

it's mostly because of ownership and permissions, try

```
su www-data (for debian)
php test.php
```

you'll probably see the error.

Comment: Already tried. It perfectly works with sudo -u www-data `php test.php`